# Manual Billing with Paypal Pro

Tags: php, paypal

Is this possible to bill a customer manually with Paypal pro?

After authorize/verify a card (not saving card number/cvv only saving it's exp. date of the card) is this possible to bill a customer manually (through cron job in PHP) according to it's subscription plan (monthly/yearly) ?

Any help ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related in any way to programming.

Comment: Cron hardly seems like the right tool for this job...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called a reference transaction.

Depending on which version of Payments Pro you have you would either use the [PayFlow](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#submitting-reference-transactions---tokenization) API or the [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) API.

This [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) supports both of those and will make the API calls very simple for you.